# TabLayout inside ViewPager is not working

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

In this [page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) Google explicitly said TabLayout can be integrated into ViewPager in layout xml file.

> **ViewPager integration**
>
> If you're using a ViewPager together with this layout, you can call
>   setupWithViewPager(ViewPager) to link the two together. This layout
>   will be automatically populated from the PagerAdapter's page titles.
>
> This view also supports being used as part of a ViewPager's decor, and
>   can be added directly to the ViewPager in a layout resource file like
>   so:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="top" />

 </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

However, whatever I tried, I cannot make TableLayout appears. Separate both is fine. I wonder is this actually working??

Comment: what you want to do?

Comment: your tablayout is must in fragment not in viewpager!

Comment: can you put your screen which you want to do!!

Comment: put your tablayout in the fragment xml file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `TabLayout` works as a `ViewPager` child as they claim.

Any view that wants to be a child of `ViewPager` has to set a boolean layout param property specific to `ViewPager` called `isDecor`.  I just looked through the source code and I don't see any place where either the `ViewPager` or `TabLayout` set this layout param property.

I think it was something they meant to do and either a) they never did it or b) there was an issue so they took it out.  Just use the TabLayout outside ViewPager, there's no real benefit to having it be a decor view.